# Webdriver + servlets, do they add up?

Tags: webdriver, interview, career-development

I was recently interviewed for a job as a developer in test, and the interviewer asked me if I had any previous experience with servlets.

This questions was totally odd because they don't use servlets at all, and I can't see how webdriver is used together with servlets.

When is servlets necessary for webdriver? To build APIs or what?

Answer (score 3):

Servlet is one of available server-side technologies to generate HTML web pages. From WebDriver point of view it is really not relevant how HTML web page it tests has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

May be interviewer is interested in developing an custom web framework/Tool.So in that case, we use servlets as server side technology to develop web applications. 
And I think this is one of the way to use, I am sure there will be multiple uses of webdriver+servlets

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that servlets are particularly ever absolutely necessary for Selenium WebDriver, but I have seen some custom cases where they are used.

One case in particular dealt with running Selenium Grid in AWS. It's actually a [github project](https://github.com/mhardin/SeleniumGridScaler) that allows you to take advantage of EC2 auto-scaling capabilities in AWS for your Selenium Grid nodes. Your test(s) talk to a servlet to get the status of the grid/nodes, and EC2 instances are spun up as nodes and attached to the hub depending on how many browsers/threads you requested to the servlet. Pretty neat stuff.